# Using titan DB from python

Tags: java, python, database, titan

I am attempting to model a network topology using Titan Graph DB. I want to specify the topology from a python application.

I have a java interface file that uses `tinkertop frames` annotation. An example structure is given below.

```
public interface IDeviceObject extends IBaseObject {

          @JsonProperty("mac")
          @Property("dl_addr")
          public String getMACAddress();
         @Property("dl_addr")
          public void setMACAddress(String macaddr);

          @JsonProperty("ipv4")
          @Property("nw_addr")
          public String getIPAddress();
          @Property("nw_addr")
          public void setIPAddress(String ipaddr);

          @JsonIgnore
          @Adjacency(label="host",direction = Direction.IN)
          public Iterable<IPortObject> getAttachedPorts();

          @JsonIgnore
          @Adjacency(label="host",direction=Direction.IN)
          public void setHostPort(final IPortObject port);

          @JsonIgnore
          @Adjacency(label="host",direction=Direction.IN)
          public void removeHostPort(final IPortObject port);

          @JsonIgnore
          @GremlinGroovy("it.in('host').in('on')")
          public Iterable<ISwitchObject> getSwitch();
    }
```

As I understand it tinkertop/frames is an ORM for Titan DB. (am I right assuming this?)

Is there something similar i.e **Object Relational Mapper for Python for Titan DB** ? I am looking at the easiest way to map my topology from Python

Comment: Have a look to bulbflow: http://bulbflow.com/overview/

Comment: Also, keep your eye out for thunderdome/Mogwai which will be re-released soon.